# focusrite 2i2 mono output

Tags: soundcard, mono

I have bought focusrite 2i2 2nd Generation since I had read ubuntu supports focusrite 2i2 somewhere on the internet. Now I realized it is just driver they support not the software. Since there is not software for focusrite 2i2 on ubuntu I can't manipulate output. At least I want to make it mono. Of course if compressor and EQ is possible it would be great. Anyone knows how to make it mono output??

Comment: What is *focusrite 2i2*? How it is connected? Bluetooth? USB (update question with `lsusb; lsusb -t`)? PCI (update your question with `lspci -knn`)?

Comment: Focusrite Scarette 2i2 is what I meant. It is a usb connected device and class compliant.